# Weird const char pointer member initialization in C struct

Tags: c

In [libwebsockets](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets) library examples there is a variable of type `struct lws_http_mount` initialized [here](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/v3.1-stable/minimal-examples/http-server/minimal-http-server-multivhost/minimal-http-server.c#L22). The `stuct lws_http_mount` was declared [here](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/v3.1-stable/include/libwebsockets/lws-context-vhost.h#L877). Below is the snippet of its declaration and definition for convenience.

```
struct lws_http_mount {
   const struct lws_http_mount *mount_next;
   const char *mountpoint;
   const char *origin;
   const char *def;
   const char *protocol;
   const struct lws_protocol_vhost_options *cgienv;
   const struct lws_protocol_vhost_options *extra_mimetypes;
   const struct lws_protocol_vhost_options *interpret;
   int cgi_timeout;
   int cache_max_age;
   unsigned int auth_mask;
   unsigned int cache_reusable:1;
   unsigned int cache_revalidate:1;
   unsigned int cache_intermediaries:1;
   unsigned char origin_protocol;
   unsigned char mountpoint_len;
   const char *basic_auth_login_file;
   void *_unused[2];
};

static const struct lws_http_mount mount_localhost1 = {
   /* .mount_next */           NULL,
   /* .mountpoint */           "/",
   /* .origin */               "./mount-origin-localhost1",
   /* .def */                  "index.html",
   /* .protocol */              NULL,
   /* .cgienv */                NULL,
   /* .extra_mimetypes */       NULL,
   /* .interpret */             NULL,
   /* .cgi_timeout */           0,
   /* .cache_max_age */         0,
   /* .auth_mask */             0,
   /* .cache_reusable */        0,
   /* .cache_revalidate */      0,
   /* .cache_intermediaries */  0,
   /* .origin_protocol */       LWSMPRO_FILE,
   /* .mountpoint_len */        1,
   /* .basic_auth_login_file */ NULL,
}
```

The member `mountpoint` of this struct is of type `const char*`. This has been initialized to `"\"` in the variable `mount_localhost1`. what will be the actual **char array size** allocated inside this struct for its member `mountpoint`?

I only know that char array member declaration inside the struct should be done as `char mountpoint[string_length]` instead of `const char* mountpoint`.

Answer (score 1):

The string literal (char array) `"/"` is created in memory, and the constant char pointer `mountpoint` is initialized with the address to that memory.

There is no "actual char array size allocated inside this struct".

It is not different from initializing a local variable like:

```c
const char *mountpoint = "/";
```

The size of the variable (const char *) is only the size of the pointer. The actual string (char array) goes [somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go), which is unrelated to the character pointer itself.

Comment: thats what I expected.

Comment: "hidden in the memory" doesn't seem like a good way of saying "somewhere else". It may well be in a read-only data segment on architectures which support such a thing.

Comment: See [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Comment: @rici and David C. Rankin: Agreed. Updated the answer.